# Ubuntu 18 (Latest) can't get the wifi card read. Hard block On. Please help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, intel-wireless, realtek-wireless

thought id grab my PC and install ubuntu on it. Have absolutely no regrets except for the fact that my wifi card isn't reading.

Ive tried all the solutions on here but I feel like I might be doing it wrong.

The wifi card is an intel Wireless 8260. Ive downloaded the drives and tried rebooting and I got nothing.

I also have a NetGear A6210 that I tried to get running using a git.. problem is no internet so I'm finding myself transfer through a USB. :(

```
 *-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 3a
   serial: 28:16:ad:77:e8:e0
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-29-generic firmware=34.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:131 memory:e1100000-e1101fff


*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: d4:81:d7:84:9a:c0
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:127 memory:e1200000-e121ffff
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3d (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1a (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.       RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Ive tried enabling but it won't enable. Any and all help is appreciated thanks..

Update : 25OCT2018

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

these were the results of running rfkill list all

Comment: *Disabled* usually means that the hardware switch is set to turn off the wireless radios. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: updated it. Seems like the the lan is hard blocked how do I take that off?

Comment: You find the wireless switch or airplane mode switch and switch it. Hard(ware) blocked means that you have to move the physical switch.

Comment: ..... thank you so much I’m very new to Linux and you just solved my issue in like a min.

Comment: could out an actual answer so I could give you the credit you deserve for bring so boss? haha thanks chili

Comment: Avoid statements like "tried everything."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled usually means that the hardware switch is set to turn off the wireless radios. You can confirm this with a terminal command:

```
rfkill list all
```

You result shows:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

Please find the wireless switch or airplane mode switch and switch it. Hard(ware) blocked means that you have to move the physical switch. There is no operating system or command line way to move the physical switch.